# Understanding the probabilistic interpretation of logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am having problem developing intuition about the probabilistic interpretation of logistic regression. Specifically, why is it valid to consider the output of logistic regression function as a probability?

Comment: please be more specific. the assumption of logistic regression is that posterior probability p(c=1|x) is a logistic function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any type of classification can be seen as a *probabilistic generative model* by modeling the class-conditional densities `p(x|C_k)` (i.e. given the class `C_k`, what's the probability of `x` belonging to that class), and the class priors `p(C_k)` (i.e. what's the probability of class `C_k`), so that we can apply Bayes' theorem to obtain the posterior probabilities `p(C_k|x)` (i.e. given x, what's the probability that it belongs to class `C_k`). It is called *generative* because, as Bishop says in his book, you could use the model to generate synthetic data by drawing values of `x` from the marginal distribution `p(x)`.

This all just means that every time you want to classify something into a specific class (e.g. size of a tumor being malignant of benign), there will be a probability of that being right or wrong.

Logistic regression uses a [sigmoid function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (or logistic function) in order to classify the data. Since this type of function ranges from 0 to 1, you can easily use it to think of it as probability distributions. Ultimately, you're looking for `p(C_k|x)` (in the example, `x`could be the size of the tumor, and C_0 the class that represents benign and C_1 malignant), and in the case of logistic regression, this is modeled by:

`p(C_k|x) = sigma( w^t x )`

where `sigma`is the sigmoid function, `w^t` is the transposed set of weights `w`, and `x`is your feature vector.

I highly recommend you read Chapter 4 of [Bishop's book](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started reading the Bishop book, but I have a lot of doubts wrt the equation that he describes in Chap-1:

p(w|D) = p(D|w).p(w) / p(D)

In a typical case, what does probability of a model (p(w)) mean? Does it mean the probability of the model being correct according to some measure? Does it mean the probability of occurrence of a model from a pool of models? Also, what does probability of data (p(D)) mean?

Thanks again!

Comment: p(w) is the probability of drawing a value from your model. This way you can synthesize new data, that's why it's called generative model. In many cases, to simplify, it is assumed to follow a Gaussian distribution. On the other hand, p(D) is the probability of having a class D. If there are only two possible classes (e.g. benign D_0 or malign D_1) then p(D_0) = 1 - P(D_1). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

• Probabilistic interpretation of Logistic regression is based on below 3 assumptions :

1. Features are real-valued Gaussian distributed.
2. Response variable is a Bernoulli random variable. For example, in a binary class problem, yi = 0 or 1.
3. For all i and j!=i, xi and xj are conditionally independent given y. (Naive Bayes assumption)

So essentially,

**Logistic-Reg = Gaussian Naive Bayes + Bernoulli class labels**

• The optimization equation that is shown in below image :

[image]

• And the equations for P(y=1 or 0/X) are show in below picture :

[image]

• If we do a little math, we can see that both geometric and probabilistic interpretations of logistic regression boils down to same thing.

• This [link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/mlbook/NBayesLogReg.pdf) can be useful to learn more regarding Logistic regression and Naive Bayes.